# Parse Json in Umbraco razor

Tags: c#, xml, json, razor, umbraco

How can i parse this Json:

```
[{
"value": "",
"date": {
  "value": "17/04/2015"
},
"hour": {
  "value": "21:00"
},
"venue": {
  "value": "some stadium."
}},  {
"value": "",
"date": {
  "value": "18/04/2015"
},
"hour": {
  "value": "20:30"
},
"venue": {
  "value": "some stadium"
}}]
```

I tried this code:

```
var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

foreach (var item in serializer.Serialize(item.dates))
{
   @* item == "34 ''" *@
}
```

but its return string "34 ''" instead what i want.

can someone help me to understand what i missed?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the `DeserializeObject`-Method instead of the `Serialize`-Method.

It returns an object[] which contains `Dictionary<string, object>`-Elements (your data)

To get the values from the array, cast the current Item to a `Dictonary<string, object>` (represents a json object) and access the value with the indexer.

Example:

```
var v = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var arr = (object[]) v.DeserializeObject(File.ReadAllText("json.txt"));
for (var i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(((Dictionary<string, object>)arr[i])["value"]);
}
```

Example 2 - Access the value inside of the date object:

```
var v = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var arr = (object[])v.DeserializeObject(File.ReadAllText("json.txt"));
for (var i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    // The current object
    var c = (Dictionary<string, object>) arr[i];
    // Getting the date object
    var date = (Dictionary<string, object>) c["date"];
    // Printing the value inside of the date object
    Console.WriteLine(date["value"]);

    // OUTPUT:
    // 17/04/2015
    // 18/04/2015
}
```

Comment: first of all many thanks for the fast answer, what kind of "target type" should i write if i have no object of this object?

Comment: Added an example to my answer, hope this answers your question

Comment: I am not sure what your problem is. Could you explain a little more what you want to do?

Comment: Sure, 
I try :)
I developing in Umbraco razor, i try to read this object and to write it into the cshtml view. 
The problem is that:
Your code succeed to readline the first level of the array which is the object called "value", but inside the value i have array that i can't parse it with 4 objects as well (value, date, hour, venue), how can i parse that 4 object?

Comment: Cast the objects into a `Dictionary<string, object>` Example: `(Dictionary<string, object>)((Dictionary<string, object>)arr[i])["date"]`